# Which is more detailed, the Junior or the Adult novelisation?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

As I have seen in a few answers using quotes from both it looks like both novelisations are QUITE different to each other. In terms of details and also in terms of the storyline they tell (small detail differences but still differences).

It has raised my curiousity about which one of the two is more detailed? Which tells more details about the happenings, the characters, their doings and their motivations, etc.

Comment: The junior novel is dramatically shorter (less than half the pages). The language is very much simplified and there's a lot more characterisation in the junior novel (explaining what people are doing and why) but much less pseudo-science.

Comment: So basically, the adult novelization is worse as a novel? :)

Comment: @Jonah - That depends. If you're aged between 8-12 years of age, you'd probably consider the adult novel to be excessively wordy and the motivations of the characters to be somewhat difficult to puzzle out.

Comment: I was saying, no pseudoscience and better characterization seems like a plus to me.

Comment: Ah, but if you're an adult, you'd probably find the junior novel to be a bit simplistic. The use of language is quite carefully chosen.

Comment: So in essence the adult novel is longer and goes more into the action/setting while teh junior goes more into characterization?

Comment: @Thomas - Yes, that's about the size of it. The junior novel was based on the adult novel (and the script) so there's very little *extra* in it.

Comment: @Richard - just post the answer already :)

Comment: @DVK-in-exile - I was waiting to see if anyone else wanted to do the legwork...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### **The Junior novel is dramatically shorter than the Adult novel (218 pages vs. 485 in the ebook versions)**

Some scenes, and especially those involving violence have been very substantially trimmed.

> The complex restraining apparatus held Rey upright against an angled platform in the cell. She woke slowly. Disoriented, at first she thought she was alone. Her oversight was understandable, since the other person in the holding area did not move, did not make a sound, and at times scarcely seemed to breathe.
>   Though startled by his unsettlingly silent presence, she took a moment to take stock of her surroundings. They were as different as could be imagined from her previous ones. The last thing she remembered was the confrontation in the forest on Takodana, the sounds of battle, and sending away the droid BB-8. That, and then the mind probe. The pain. Her efforts to shut it out, and the contemptuous ease with which her mental defenses had been brushed aside. Even now, there was a lingering ache at the back of her eyes.
>   The forest was gone. So was Maz’s castle. Bereft of a point of reference, she had no choice but to ask.
>   “Where am I?” - **Adult novel**

versus

> Rey woke to find herself bound to an interrogation bench, tilted almost to a standing position. The interrogator himself lurked nearby, watching her through his metal mask.
>   “Where am I?” she asked him.  - **Junior novel**

---

### There's a great deal more internal voice explaining why characters are acting the way they are

> His head came up as the door to the holding cell whooshed open and a
>   stormtrooper entered. At least, Poe mused, it would be over soon. He
>   could look forward to freedom from any further tormenting thoughts.
>   The trooper’s words to the room’s single guard surprised him, however.
>   “I’m taking the prisoner to Kylo Ren.”  - **Adult novel**

versus

> FN-2187 made a choice. Or more truthfully, after he’d considered all his options that didn’t involve interrogation, imprisonment, or execution, the choice made him.
>   He couldn’t have stopped the massacre on Jakku if he’d wanted. His squad mates would’ve turned their rifles on him. But there was something he might be able to do. Someone he might be able to save from Kylo Ren.  - **Junior novel**

---

### There's a lot more "tech-speak" in the adult novel

> THE INTERIOR OF the TIE fighter was spotless. Droids and techs had done their work well, leaving it ready for pilot and gunner. It was a true pilot who now settled himself into the cockpit command seat. As to the other missing crew member, that remained to be seen.
>   Slipping free of his bloody, confining jacket, Poe examined the controls laid out before him. Some were familiar from his professional studies of First Order ships, others from perusing details of Old Imperial craft. What he didn’t recognize immediately, he felt sure he could work around. A modern fighter like this one would be naturally forgiving, its computational components engineered to compensate for pilot miscues and oversights. He was relying on the likelihood that the ship itself would automatically correct for any minor mistakes in judgment. - **Adult novel**

versus

> Once he saw the TIE fighter, Poe Dameron forgot about his pain.
>   Here was something he could handle. Two wings attached to twin ion engines. Built out of metal, held together by bolts. Nothing mystical about it, all mechanical. - **Junior novel**

---

### The language (word choice) in the junior novel is a lot more simplistic

> Halting an arm’s length from his father, Ren unclipped his lightsaber, looked down at it for a moment, and then extended it toward Han. For an instant that seemed to extend into forever, nothing happened. Smiling, Han reached for the weapon. Then, as the light from outside was fully blocked by the flow of descending, accumulating dark energy, Ren ignited the lightsaber  - **Adult novel**

versus

> Ben unbelted his lightsaber hilt and held it out. Han looked at the hilt and then at his son. Finally, he reached for it.
>   “Thank you,” Ben said. He ignited the lightsaber. - **Junior novel**

---

### The Adult novel contains additional scenes that don't occur in the film. The Junior novel is closer to the original script.

> “I’m taking the prisoner to Kylo Ren.”
>   Poe sagged in his seat. What more did they want from him? Everything, anything of value that he had known was now known to them. Had they overlooked some line of questioning? He could not think of one. But then, at the moment, his mind was not functioning properly.
>   The guard wondered, too. “I was not told to expect you. Why would Ren wish to question the prisoner outside the cell?”
>   The new arrival’s voice darkened. “Do you dare to question Kylo Ren’s motives?”
>   “No, no, that’s not what I meant! I…” Without another word, the guard proceeded to release the prisoner from his shackles. It took twice as long as it should have, since in his sudden nervousness he kept fumbling the task. - **Adult novel**

versus

> “I’m taking the prisoner to Kylo Ren,” FN-2187 told the cell guard.
>   Mere mention of Ren’s name provoked the guard to action. He freed the prisoner from the chair and lifted him to his feet. FN-2187 did the rest, shoving the pilot through the doorway. - **Junior novel**

Comment: @Richard The paragraphs from your "internal voice" examples don't seem to be covering the same moment in time, and thus don't give us any insight into the differences between the two versions of the novel in that regard. Could you paragraphs that are more analogous, as you did for your other examples?

Comment: @user45623 - Actually it's exactly the same place; "a stormtrooper entered" is what we get in the adult novel in place of the two paragraphs of exposition in the Junior novel. You're right though, I'm sure I can come up with a better example. Bear with me.

Comment: I see. I think that the connection would be much clearer if you included the next sentence, which appears to be `“I’m taking the prisoner to Kylo Ren,” FN-2187 told the cell guard.` However, it appears that the adult novel covers that scene from Poe's perspective, while the junior novel covers it from FN-2187's perspective, so naturally the exposition will be completely different and it isn't the best example.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a Star Wars question, per se. The answer is universal to any subject and genre. So, although I haven't read either of the novelizations of TFA, I will answer your question anyway:

The Junior edition (of any novel that has one) is intended for children or young adults, and is *always* shorter and less detailed than the full-length novel, essentially by definition. It might go into a bit more detail on things that an adult reader would need no explanation for (think a thirty second visual metaphor of a pen orbiting around people in a meeting room instead of saying "slingshot maneuver"), or might dwell on details that are more interesting to children (e.g. spend more time focusing on someone's cute pet or the bumbling antics of the comic relief), but will almost never include any significant new details that were left out of the full novel.

You might, in some cases, get the impression that the junior novel is providing more information when it violates the "show-not-tell" principle and bluntly tells you something like 'X has a crush on Y', when in fact this is information that an adult reader would infer out of events and actions in the full novel.

In terms of adult and junior versions being quite different, that can arise out of the aforementioned circumstances, as well as a need to remove overtly "adult" themes. If I remember correctly, the junior novelization of *Shadows of the Empire* abandons most or all of the sexual themes in the adult novel, which has a big impact on the story as a whole.

Again, all of these things are implied in calling a novel the "junior" version. A publisher would never use the term "junior" on a version that contained more detail and a deeper look into the events in question.